# Repairing ArcGIS Server Installation?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, installation

Due to problems with creating AGS Services I have been told I should do a "repair" of ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Server.

Does anyone know if there is a utility or tool to do this?

Comment: Double-click on the Windows installed software package and choose "Repair" instead of "Remove" (or remove then reinstall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do a repair or uninstall, go into Add/Remove Programs, right click on ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Server in the list, select Uninstall/Change, and go from there. I've done uninstall/reinstalls *too* many times, and found that the repair takes just as long as a full uninstall/reinstall (or so it seems), and oftentimes doesn't fully fix the issue. So, when forced to go to this extreme, I (and most of my colleagues) just do a full uninstall/reinstall versus a repair.

*However*, another thing to try first is to reset the ArcGIS Server Account, which will usually take care of permissions issues and only takes a couple of minutes, so it's worth a shot. Start > Programs > ArcGIS > ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Server > Configure ArcGIS Server Account. No idea what your particular issue is, but like I said, it only takes a couple of minutes to do this.